# Digital isolator: Output is not coming as expected

Tags: power-electronics, opto-isolator, digital-isolator

[image]

Im using digital isolator to isolate my PWM signals. Output VO does show any PWM output. What may be the issue here. I have used 1kohm at R1.
Input side:

PWM_H_In : PWM signal from function generator
PWM_L_In : SGND

Output side Supply:
VDDH: +6V
VEEH: -3V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have filtered the PWM away with the 0.1 uF capacitor.

Comment: I removed the 0.1uF, i can see PWM output now. However output level is 2X of input.

Comment: @RohanKharvi If so, then that's a neat observation what your circuit does. I don't know what you expected to see and why.